# How can this be done in a single select statement?

Tags: mysql, database, select

I've got these three tables in the DB & I want to select the event_name for a specific userID from t1event given that I know the value of ID from t1user. How can I do this in a single select statement. (I am using mysql).

```
**t1user**
+----+
| ID |
+----+
```

```
**t2userEvent**
+---------+----------+
| userID  |  eventID |
+---------+----------+
```

```
**t1event**
+----------+--------------+
| eventID  |   event_name |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Really, you should at least *try* to solve the problem.  Please edit your question with a query that you have attempted.

Comment: Very helpful thank you.What I am doing doesn't involve a lot of database stuff. but I suck at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join:

```
SELECT t1user.ID, t1event.event_name
FROM t1user
JOIN t2userEvent ON t1user.ID = t2userEvent.userID
JOIN t1event ON t1event.eventID = t2userEvent.eventID
WHERE t1user.ID = :user_id
```

If you want the users who doesn't have events be listed too, then use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT A.event_name FROM t1event A INNER JOIN t2userEvent B  
ON A.eventID = B.eventID WHERE b.userID = ?
```

If I understand it correctly you have the userID as parameter?